# Problem with font map

Tags: fonts, pdftex, texlive

Compiling a `beamer` project, I get the following error:

```
mktexpk: /home/matthieu/.texlive2012/texmf-var/fonts/pk/ljfour/public/cm/cmss8.525pk: successfully generated.
 </home/matthieu/.texlive2012/texmf
-var/fonts/pk/ljfour/public/cm/cmss8.525pk>
kpathsea: Running mktexpk --mfmode / --bdpi 600 --mag 0+525/600 --dpi 525 mathkerncmssi8
mktexpk: don't know how to create bitmap font for mathkerncmssi8.
mktexpk: perhaps mathkerncmssi8 is missing from the map file.
kpathsea: Appending font creation commands to missfont.log.

!pdfTeX error: /usr/bin/pdflatex (file mathkerncmssi8): Font mathkerncmssi8 at 
525 not found
 ==> Fatal error occurred, no output PDF file produced!
```

Reading some answers, I added `\pdfmapfile{+sansmathaccent.map}` to my `.tex` file and the compilation worked but I want to solve the problem.

Hence I also tried to run `updmap-sys` and `mktexlsr` but I got lost between the locations of the map files...

I copy below the output of these two commands. If anyone can help me...

```
[root@localhost matthieu]# updmap-sys /usr/share/texmf/fonts/map/pdftex/updmap/pdftex.mapupdmap is using the following updmap.cfg files (in precedence order):   /etc/texmf/web2c/updmap.cfg dvips output dir: "/var/lib/texmf/fonts/map/dvips/updmap" pdftex output dir: "/var/lib/texmf/fonts/map/pdftex/updmap" dvipdfmx output dir: "/var/lib/texmf/fonts/map/dvipdfmx/updmap" pxdvi output dir: "/var/lib/texmf/fonts/map/pxdvi/updmap"

updmap is creating new map files using the following configuration:   LW35 font names                  : URWkb (/etc/texmf/web2c/updmap.cfg) prefer outlines                  : true (/etc/texmf/web2c/updmap.cfg)  texhash enabled                  : true   download standard fonts (dvips)  : false (/etc/texmf/web2c/updmap.cfg)   download standard fonts (pdftex) : true (/etc/texmf/web2c/updmap.cfg)   kanjiEmbed replacement string    : noEmbed (default)   kanjiVariant replacement string  :  (default)   create a mapfile for pxdvi       : false (default)

Scanning for LW35 support files  [  3 files] Scanning for MixedMap entries    [ 37 files] Scanning for KanjiMap entries    [  0 files] Scanning for Map entries         [ 73 files]

Generating output for dvipdfmx... Generating output for ps2pk... Generating output for dvips... Generating output for pdftex...

Files generated:   /var/lib/texmf/fonts/map/dvips/updmap:
       11448 2013-05-22 16:04:24 builtin35.map
       15911 2013-05-22 16:04:24 download35.map
      324599 2013-05-22 16:04:24 psfonts_pk.map
      577080 2013-05-22 16:04:24 psfonts_t1.map
      577075 2013-05-22 16:04:24 ps2pk.map
          14 2013-05-22 16:04:24 psfonts.map -> psfonts_t1.map   /var/lib/texmf/fonts/map/pdftex/updmap:
      577082 2013-05-22 16:04:24 pdftex_dl14.map
      575509 2013-05-22 16:04:24 pdftex_ndl14.map
          15 2013-05-22 16:04:24 pdftex.map -> pdftex_dl14.map   /var/lib/texmf/fonts/map/dvipdfmx/updmap:
         281 2013-05-22 16:04:24 kanjix.map

Transcript written on "/var/lib/texmf/web2c/updmap.log". updmap: Updating ls-R files.

[root@localhost matthieu]# mktexlsr mktexlsr: Updating /etc/texmf/ls-R...  mktexlsr: Updating /usr/share/texmf/ls-R...  mktexlsr: Updating /usr/share/texmf-dist/ls-R...  mktexlsr: Updating /usr/share/texmf-local/ls-R...  mktexlsr: Updating /var/lib/texmf/ls-R...  mktexlsr: Done.
```

Comment: Check if the pdftex.map written by updmap-sys is actually the one used by pdftex (the path is in the log-file).

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SX! You may have a look on [our starter guide](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/1436).

Comment: cat GT_Deneufchatel.log | grep pdftex.map yields
{/var/lib/texmf/fonts/map/pdftex/updmap/pdftex.map}] and updmap-sys generates these files: /var/lib/texmf/fonts/map/pdftex/updmap:
      577082 2013-05-22 18:39:51 pdftex_dl14.map
      575509 2013-05-22 18:39:51 pdftex_ndl14.map
          15 2013-05-22 18:39:51 pdftex.map -> pdftex_dl14.map

Comment: In the output of the compilation with pdflatex appears the location /root/.texlive2012/texmf-var/fonts/map/pdftex/updmap/pdftex.map. Is it related to my problem ?

Comment: The `mathkerncmss10` font is used by a recent version of the `sansmathaccent`. Maybe you've improperly installed it.

Comment: I installed Mageia 3 a few days ago and never changed anything about the fonts!

Comment: Well if the map file created is not the one used this is certainly related to the problem. The path starting with `/root/.texlive2012/texmf-var` sounds as if the map file in use has been created by `updmap` (and not `updmap-sys`). In this case you must update it with `updmap`.

Comment: I tried cp /var/lib/texmf/fonts/map/pdftex/updmap/pdftex_dl14.map /root/.texlive2012/texmf-var/fonts/map/pdftex/updmap/pdftex.map but it does not change anything.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It looks like you are using a distribution which either does not properly activate installed map files.

First, your invocation of `updmap` is wrong. You cannot call `updmap` with the full path of a map file, please see the man page of `updmap --help` for correct syntax. The normal solution would be to call

```
updmap-sys --enable Map sansmathaccent.map
```

which should be enough. Since your distribution uses only `/etc/texmf/web2c/updmap.cfg` you also could edit this file and add one line

```
Map sansmathaccent.map
```

followed by a call to `updmap-sys`.

In case your distribution installed sansmathaccent.map, you should write a bug report to the distribution as they have not properly set up the map activation system (I *really* should write that article on how to distribute TeX Live!!!)

Comment: I have same problem, but I do $ updmap --enable Map sansmathaccent.map in Fedora 22, Texlive 2014

Comment: `updmap` creates config files within the home directory of the calling user, These files will take precedence over system files, even if the system files are newer.