# Is Texlive 2017 pdftex supposed to use /usr/local/texlive/2017/texmf-var/?

Tags: fonts, paths

I am having [this problem](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/115765/problem-with-font-map). I have found out that the missing font is correctly specified in

```
/usr/local/texlive/2017/texmf-dist/fonts/map/pdftex/updmap/pdftex.map
```

but when I run pdflatex on my document, it sources

```
/usr/local/texlive/2017/texmf-var/fonts/map/pdftex/updmap/pdftex.map
```

instead. Notice `texmf-var` instead of `texmf-dist`. `kpsewhich pdftex.map` says to use this path, so I guess it does as expected.

The problem is that the `mathkerncmssi*` fonts are missing from `/usr/local/texlive/2017/texmf-var/fonts/map/pdftex/updmap/pdftex.map`, but they are in `/usr/local/texlive/2017/texmf-dist/fonts/map/pdftex/updmap/pdftex.map`.

Should pdflatex in fact be using `/usr/local/texlive/2017/texmf-dist/fonts/map/pdftex/updmap/pdftex.map` and if not; how did I end up with the fonts missing from `/usr/local/texlive/2017/texmf-var/fonts/map/pdftex/updmap/pdftex.map` and how should I get them back?

*Bonus info:* `/usr/local/texlive/2017/texmf-var/fonts/map/pdftex/updmap/pdftex.map` in my installation is a symbolic link to `pdftex_dl14.map`. Also, running `updmap-sys` does not solve the problem. Here is the output of `updmap-sys`:

```
updmap will read the following updmap.cfg files (in precedence order):
  /usr/local/texlive/2017/texmf-dist/web2c/updmap.cfg
updmap may write changes to the following updmap.cfg file:
  /usr/local/texlive/2017/texmf-config/web2c/updmap.cfg
dvips output dir: "/usr/local/texlive/2017/texmf-var/fonts/map/dvips/updmap"
pdftex output dir: "/usr/local/texlive/2017/texmf-var/fonts/map/pdftex/updmap"
dvipdfmx output dir: "/usr/local/texlive/2017/texmf-var/fonts/map/dvipdfmx/updmap"

updmap is creating new map files
using the following configuration:
  LW35 font names                  : URWkb (/usr/local/texlive/2017/texmf-dist/web2c/updmap.cfg)
  prefer outlines                  : true (/usr/local/texlive/2017/texmf-dist/web2c/updmap.cfg)
  texhash enabled                  : true
  download standard fonts (dvips)  : true (/usr/local/texlive/2017/texmf-dist/web2c/updmap.cfg)
  download standard fonts (pdftex) : true (/usr/local/texlive/2017/texmf-dist/web2c/updmap.cfg)
  jaEmbed replacement string       : ipaex (/usr/local/texlive/2017/texmf-dist/web2c/updmap.cfg)
  jaVariant replacement string     : <empty> (default)
  scEmbed replacement string       : arphic (/usr/local/texlive/2017/texmf-dist/web2c/updmap.cfg)
  tcEmbed replacement string       : arphic (/usr/local/texlive/2017/texmf-dist/web2c/updmap.cfg)
  koEmbed replacement string       : baekmuk (/usr/local/texlive/2017/texmf-dist/web2c/updmap.cfg)
  create a mapfile for pxdvi       : false (default)

Scanning for LW35 support files  [  3 files]
Scanning for MixedMap entries    [  8 files]
Scanning for KanjiMap entries    [  0 files]
Scanning for Map entries         [  4 files]

Generating output for dvipdfmx...
Generating output for ps2pk...
Generating output for dvips...
Generating output for pdftex...

Files generated:
  /usr/local/texlive/2017/texmf-var/fonts/map/dvips/updmap:
       15796 2018-04-09 10:37:10 builtin35.map
       21269 2018-04-09 10:37:10 download35.map
       25068 2018-04-09 10:37:10 psfonts_pk.map
       29246 2018-04-09 10:37:10 psfonts_t1.map
       29241 2018-04-09 10:37:10 ps2pk.map
          14 2018-04-09 10:37:10 psfonts.map -> psfonts_t1.map
  /usr/local/texlive/2017/texmf-var/fonts/map/pdftex/updmap:
       29248 2018-04-09 10:37:10 pdftex_dl14.map
       27583 2018-04-09 10:37:10 pdftex_ndl14.map
          15 2018-04-09 10:37:10 pdftex.map -> pdftex_dl14.map
  /usr/local/texlive/2017/texmf-var/fonts/map/dvipdfmx/updmap:
         319 2018-04-09 10:37:10 kanjix.map

Transcript written on "/usr/local/texlive/2017/texmf-var/web2c/updmap.log".
updmap: Updating ls-R files.
```

Comment: I certainly expect the current pdftex.map to be in texmf-var -- it is regenerated frequently after installations and also should take local maps into account. What is the output of updmap-sys?

Comment: @UlrikeFischer I have updated the question with the output now.

Comment: OK, so now I see that the used pdftex.map is indeed being updated (as pdftex_dl14.map). Somehow, those mathkern fonts are not included there. Adding `\pdfmapfile{+sansmathaccent.map}` locally in my LaTeX file is able to locally fix the problem, but I would like to fix the root cause.

Comment: What happens if you call `updmap-sys --enable Map sansmathaccent.map`?

Comment: Well that actually seems to fix it, thanks.
I wonder why this happened? I have never had to manually add this before. With Texlive 2016 and previous versions I never saw this problem...

Comment: I copied this line from the accepted answer in the question you linked too. So I would say your question is a duplicate and will close it.

Comment: Embarrasingly, at first glance I felt convinced that was not my problem. It was only after proper investigation and your help that I realised, it was :o)