# Error when including letters in Math environment in beamer

Tags: beamer, amsmath

I am trying to make a presentation in beamer. However when I include letters in the math environment I get the following error message:

```
!pdfTeX error: pdflatex (file mathkerncmssi8): Font mathkerncmssi8 at 525 not f
ound
==> Fatal error occurred, no output PDF file produced!
```

What am I doing wrong?

```
\documentclass[10pt]{beamer}
\usetheme{Copenhagen}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{amsfonts}
\usepackage{amssymb}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\title{Test}

\begin{document}

\begin{frame}
\titlepage
\end{frame}


\begin{frame}
$r_d$
\end{frame}

\end{document}
```

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SE. Can I ask some informations? I compile correctly your code. Which operating system do you use and have you updated your LaTeX distribution?

Comment: Maybe this answer can help you: https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/64790/36296 Or maybe this: https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/115873/36296

Comment: Thank you. The first link resolved the problem.