# itemize and equation in beamer

Tags: beamer, math-mode, miktex

I am not able to get the output of this file, however the same code was running successfully in my office computer but in my personal laptop (even though no error is displayed in red color), I am not able to get the output PDF of this code in. I updated my texmaker but the problem persists. The problem is with the $m_d$ in itemize. Please suggest what to do?

```
\documentclass{beamer}
\mode<presentation> {
\usecolortheme{seahorse}
}
\usepackage[export]{adjustbox}
\usepackage{wrapfig, lipsum}
\usepackage{booktabs} 
\begin{document}
\begin{frame}
\begin{itemize}
\item Chiral Symmetry  $m_d$
\end{itemize}
\end{frame}
\end{document}
```

LOG FILE :

```
("C:\Program Files\MiKTeX 2.9\tex\generic\pgf\basiclayer\pgfcore.code.tex"
Package: pgfcore 2010/04/11 v3.0.1a (rcs-revision 1.7)
("C:\Program Files\MiKTeX 2.9\tex\generic\pgf\math\pgfmath.code.tex"
("C:\Program Files\MiKTeX 2.9\tex\generic\pgf\math\pgfmathcalc.code.tex"
("C:\Program Files\MiKTeX 2.9\tex\generic\pgf\math\pgfmathutil.code.tex")
("C:\Program Files\MiKTeX 2.9\tex\generic\pgf\math\pgfmathparser.code.tex"
)
("C:\Program Files\MiKTeX 2.9\tex\generic\pgf\math\pgfmathfunctions.code.tex"
("C:\Program Files\MiKTeX 2.9\tex\generic\pgf\math\pgfmathfunctions.basic.code.
tex")
("C:\Program Files\MiKTeX 2.9\tex\generic\pgf\math\pgfmathfunctions.trigonometr
ic.code.tex")
("C:\Program Files\MiKTeX 2.9\tex\generic\pgf\math\pgfmathfunctions.random.code
.tex")
("C:\Program Files\MiKTeX 2.9\tex\generic\pgf\math\pgfmathfunctions.comparison.
code.tex")
("C:\Program Files\MiKTeX 2.9\tex\generic\pgf\math\pgfmathfunctions.base.code.t
ex")
("C:\Program Files\MiKTeX 2.9\tex\generic\pgf\math\pgfmathfunctions.round.code.
tex")
("C:\Program Files\MiKTeX 2.9\tex\generic\pgf\math\pgfmathfunctions.misc.code.t
ex")
("C:\Program Files\MiKTeX 2.9\tex\generic\pgf\math\pgfmathfunctions.integerarit
hmetics.code.tex")))
("C:\Program Files\MiKTeX 2.9\tex\generic\pgf\math\pgfmathfloat.code.tex"
\c@pgfmathroundto@lastzeros=\count114
))
("C:\Program Files\MiKTeX 2.9\tex\generic\pgf\basiclayer\pgfcorepoints.code.tex
"
File: pgfcorepoints.code.tex 2013/10/07 (rcs-revision 1.27)
("C:\Program Files\MiKTeX 2.9\tex\generic\pgf\basiclayer\pgfcorepathconstruct.c
ode.tex"
File: pgfcorepathconstruct.code.tex 2013/10/07 (rcs-revision 1.29)
\pgf@path@lastx=\dimen153
\pgf@path@lasty=\dimen154
)
("C:\Program Files\MiKTeX 2.9\tex\generic\pgf\basiclayer\pgfcorepathusage.code.
tex"
File: pgfcorepathusage.code.tex 2014/11/02 (rcs-revision 1.24)
\pgf@shorten@end@additional=\dimen155
\pgf@shorten@start@additional=\dimen156
)
("C:\Program Files\MiKTeX 2.9\tex\generic\pgf\basiclayer\pgfcorescopes.code.tex
"
File: pgfcorescopes.code.tex 2015/05/08 (rcs-revision 1.46)
\pgfpic=\box36
\pgf@hbox=\box37
\pgf@layerbox@main=\box38
\pgf@picture@serial@count=\count115
)
("C:\Program Files\MiKTeX 2.9\tex\generic\pgf\basiclayer\pgfcoregraphicstate.co
de.tex"
File: pgfcoregraphicstate.code.tex 2014/11/02 (rcs-revision 1.12)
\pgflinewidth=\dimen157
)
("C:\Program Files\MiKTeX 2.9\tex\generic\pgf\basiclayer\pgfcoretransformations
.code.tex"
File: pgfcoretransformations.code.tex 2015/08/07 (rcs-revision 1.20)
\pgf@pt@x=\dimen158
\pgf@pt@y=\dimen159
\pgf@pt@temp=\dimen160
)
("C:\Program Files\MiKTeX 2.9\tex\generic\pgf\basiclayer\pgfcorequick.code.tex"
File: pgfcorequick.code.tex 2008/10/09 (rcs-revision 1.3)
)
("C:\Program Files\MiKTeX 2.9\tex\generic\pgf\basiclayer\pgfcoreobjects.code.te
x"
File: pgfcoreobjects.code.tex 2006/10/11 (rcs-revision 1.2)
)
("C:\Program Files\MiKTeX 2.9\tex\generic\pgf\basiclayer\pgfcorepathprocessing.
code.tex"
File: pgfcorepathprocessing.code.tex 2013/09/09 (rcs-revision 1.9)
)
("C:\Program Files\MiKTeX 2.9\tex\generic\pgf\basiclayer\pgfcorearrows.code.tex
"
File: pgfcorearrows.code.tex 2015/05/14 (rcs-revision 1.43)
\pgfarrowsep=\dimen161
)
("C:\Program Files\MiKTeX 2.9\tex\generic\pgf\basiclayer\pgfcoreshade.code.tex"
File: pgfcoreshade.code.tex 2013/07/15 (rcs-revision 1.15)
\pgf@max=\dimen162
\pgf@sys@shading@range@num=\count116
) ("C:\Program Files\MiKTeX 2.9\tex\generic\pgf\basiclayer\pgfcoreimage.code.te
x"
File: pgfcoreimage.code.tex 2013/07/15 (rcs-revision 1.18)
("C:\Program Files\MiKTeX 2.9\tex\generic\pgf\basiclayer\pgfcoreexternal.code.t
ex"
File: pgfcoreexternal.code.tex 2014/07/09 (rcs-revision 1.21)
\pgfexternal@startupbox=\box39
))
("C:\Program Files\MiKTeX 2.9\tex\generic\pgf\basiclayer\pgfcorelayers.code.tex
"
File: pgfcorelayers.code.tex 2013/07/18 (rcs-revision 1.7)
)
("C:\Program Files\MiKTeX 2.9\tex\generic\pgf\basiclayer\pgfcoretransparency.co
de.tex"
File: pgfcoretransparency.code.tex 2013/09/30 (rcs-revision 1.5)
)
("C:\Program Files\MiKTeX 2.9\tex\generic\pgf\basiclayer\pgfcorepatterns.code.t
ex"
File: pgfcorepatterns.code.tex 2013/11/07 (rcs-revision 1.5)
))) ("C:\Program Files\MiKTeX 2.9\tex\latex\pgf\utilities\xxcolor.sty"
Package: xxcolor 2003/10/24 ver 0.1
\XC@nummixins=\count117
\XC@countmixins=\count118
)
("C:\Program Files\MiKTeX 2.9\tex\generic\oberdiek\atbegshi.sty"
Package: atbegshi 2016/06/09 v1.18 At begin shipout hook (HO)
("C:\Program Files\MiKTeX 2.9\tex\generic\oberdiek\infwarerr.sty"
Package: infwarerr 2016/05/16 v1.4 Providing info/warning/error messages (HO)
)
("C:\Program Files\MiKTeX 2.9\tex\generic\oberdiek\ltxcmds.sty"
Package: ltxcmds 2016/05/16 v1.23 LaTeX kernel commands for general use (HO)
))
("C:\Program Files\MiKTeX 2.9\tex\latex\hyperref\hyperref.sty"
Package: hyperref 2018/02/06 v6.86b Hypertext links for LaTeX
("C:\Program Files\MiKTeX 2.9\tex\generic\oberdiek\hobsub-hyperref.sty"
Package: hobsub-hyperref 2016/05/16 v1.14 Bundle oberdiek, subset hyperref (HO)
("C:\Program Files\MiKTeX 2.9\tex\generic\oberdiek\hobsub-generic.sty"
Package ifluatex Info: LuaTeX not detected.
Package hobsub Info: Skipping package `ifvtex' (already loaded).
Package etexcmds Info: Could not find \expanded.
(etexcmds) That can mean that you are not using pdfTeX 1.50 or
(etexcmds) that some package has redefined \expanded.
(etexcmds) In the latter case, load this package earlier.
Package: kvsetkeys 2016/05/16 v1.17 Key value parser (HO)
Package: kvdefinekeys 2016/05/16 v1.4 Define keys (HO)
Package: pdftexcmds 2018/01/21 v0.26 Utility functions of pdfTeX for LuaTeX (HO
)
Package pdftexcmds Info: LuaTeX not detected.
Package pdftexcmds Info: \pdf@primitive is available.
Package pdftexcmds Info: \pdf@ifprimitive is available.
Package pdftexcmds Info: \pdfdraftmode found.
Package: pdfescape 2016/05/16 v1.14 Implements pdfTeX's escape features (HO)
Package: bigintcalc 2016/05/16 v1.4 Expandable calculations on big integers (HO
)
Package: bitset 2016/05/16 v1.2 Handle bit-vector datatype (HO)
Package: uniquecounter 2016/05/16 v1.3 Provide unlimited unique counter (HO)
)
Package hobsub Info: Skipping package `hobsub' (already loaded).
Package: letltxmacro 2016/05/16 v1.5 Let assignment for LaTeX macros (HO)
Package: hopatch 2016/05/16 v1.3 Wrapper for package hooks (HO)
Package: xcolor-patch 2016/05/16 xcolor patch
Package: atveryend 2016/05/16 v1.9 Hooks at the very end of document (HO)
Package hobsub Info: Skipping package `atbegshi' (already loaded).
Package: refcount 2016/05/16 v3.5 Data extraction from label references (HO)
Package: hycolor 2016/05/16 v1.8 Color options for hyperref/bookmark (HO)
)
("C:\Program Files\MiKTeX 2.9\tex\latex\oberdiek\auxhook.sty"
Package: auxhook 2016/05/16 v1.4 Hooks for auxiliary files (HO)
)
("C:\Program Files\MiKTeX 2.9\tex\latex\oberdiek\kvoptions.sty"
Package: kvoptions 2016/05/16 v3.12 Key value format for package options (HO)
)
\@linkdim=\dimen163
\Hy@linkcounter=\count119
\Hy@pagecounter=\count120
("C:\Program Files\MiKTeX 2.9\tex\latex\hyperref\pd1enc.def"
File: pd1enc.def 2018/02/06 v6.86b Hyperref: PDFDocEncoding definition (HO)
)
\Hy@SavedSpaceFactor=\count121
("C:\Program Files\MiKTeX 2.9\tex\latex\00miktex\hyperref.cfg"
File: hyperref.cfg 2002/06/06 v1.2 hyperref configuration of TeXLive
)
\c@Hy@tempcnt=\count122
("C:\Program Files\MiKTeX 2.9\tex\latex\url\url.sty"
\Urlmuskip=\muskip10
Package: url 2013/09/16 ver 3.4 Verb mode for urls, etc.
)
Package hyperref Message: Stopped early.
)
Package hyperref Info: Driver (autodetected): hpdftex.
("C:\Program Files\MiKTeX 2.9\tex\latex\hyperref\hpdftex.def"
File: hpdftex.def 2018/02/06 v6.86b Hyperref driver for pdfTeX
\Fld@listcount=\count125
\c@bookmark@seq@number=\count126
("C:\Program Files\MiKTeX 2.9\tex\latex\oberdiek\rerunfilecheck.sty"
Package: rerunfilecheck 2016/05/16 v1.8 Rerun checks for auxiliary files (HO)
Package uniquecounter Info: New unique counter `rerunfilecheck' on input line 2
82.
))
("C:\Program Files\MiKTeX 2.9\tex\latex\beamer\beamerbaserequires.sty"
("C:\Program Files\MiKTeX 2.9\tex\latex\beamer\beamerbasecompatibility.sty")
("C:\Program Files\MiKTeX 2.9\tex\latex\beamer\beamerbasefont.sty"
("C:\Program Files\MiKTeX 2.9\tex\latex\amsfonts\amssymb.sty"
Package: amssymb 2013/01/14 v3.01 AMS font symbols
("C:\Program Files\MiKTeX 2.9\tex\latex\amsfonts\amsfonts.sty"
Package: amsfonts 2013/01/14 v3.01 Basic AMSFonts support
\@emptytoks=\toks26
\symAMSa=\mathgroup4
\symAMSb=\mathgroup5
LaTeX Font Info: Overwriting math alphabet `\mathfrak' in version `bold'
(Font) U/euf/m/n --> U/euf/b/n on input line 106.
))
("C:\Program Files\MiKTeX 2.9\tex\latex\sansmathaccent\sansmathaccent.sty"
Package: sansmathaccent 2013/03/28
("C:\Program Files\MiKTeX 2.9\tex\latex\filehook\filehook.sty"
Package: filehook 2011/10/12 v0.5d Hooks for input files
)))
("C:\Program Files\MiKTeX 2.9\tex\latex\beamer\beamerbasetranslator.sty"
("C:\Program Files\MiKTeX 2.9\tex\latex\translator\translator.sty"
Package: translator 2018/01/04 v1.12 Easy translation of strings in LaTeX
))
("C:\Program Files\MiKTeX 2.9\tex\latex\beamer\beamerbasemisc.sty")
("C:\Program Files\MiKTeX 2.9\tex\latex\beamer\beamerbasetwoscreens.sty")
("C:\Program Files\MiKTeX 2.9\tex\latex\beamer\beamerbaseoverlay.sty"
\beamer@argscount=\count127
\beamer@lastskipcover=\skip44
\beamer@trivlistdepth=\count128
)
("C:\Program Files\MiKTeX 2.9\tex\latex\beamer\beamerbasetitle.sty")
("C:\Program Files\MiKTeX 2.9\tex\latex\beamer\beamerbasesection.sty"
)
("C:\Program Files\MiKTeX 2.9\tex\latex\beamer\beamerbaseframe.sty"
\beamer@framebox=\box40
\beamer@frametitlebox=\box41
\beamer@zoombox=\box42
\beamer@zoomcount=\count134
\beamer@zoomframecount=\count135
\beamer@frametextheight=\dimen167
\c@subsectionslide=\count136
\beamer@frametopskip=\skip45
\beamer@framebottomskip=\skip46
\beamer@frametopskipautobreak=\skip47
\beamer@framebottomskipautobreak=\skip48
\beamer@envbody=\toks27
\framewidth=\dimen168
\c@framenumber=\count137
)
("C:\Program Files\MiKTeX 2.9\tex\latex\beamer\beamerbaseverbatim.sty"
\beamer@verbatimfileout=\write4
)
("C:\Program Files\MiKTeX 2.9\tex\latex\beamer\beamerbaseframesize.sty"
\beamer@splitbox=\box43
\beamer@framesubtitletoks=\toks29
)
("C:\Program Files\MiKTeX 2.9\tex\latex\beamer\beamerbaseframecomponents.sty"
\beamer@footins=\box44
)
("C:\Program Files\MiKTeX 2.9\tex\latex\beamer\beamerbasecolor.sty")
("C:\Program Files\MiKTeX 2.9\tex\latex\beamer\beamerbasenotes.sty"
\beamer@frameboxcopy=\box45
)
("C:\Program Files\MiKTeX 2.9\tex\latex\beamer\beamerbasetoc.sty")
("C:\Program Files\MiKTeX 2.9\tex\latex\beamer\beamerbasetemplates.sty"
\beamer@sbttoks=\toks30
("C:\Program Files\MiKTeX 2.9\tex\latex\beamer\beamerbaseauxtemplates.sty"
("C:\Program Files\MiKTeX 2.9\tex\latex\beamer\beamerbaseboxes.sty"
\bmb@box=\box46
\bmb@colorbox=\box47
\bmb@boxshadow=\box48
\bmb@boxshadowball=\box49
\bmb@boxshadowballlarge=\box50
\bmb@temp=\dimen170
\bmb@dima=\dimen171
\bmb@dimb=\dimen172
\bmb@prevheight=\dimen173
)
\beamer@blockheadheight=\dimen174
))
("C:\Program Files\MiKTeX 2.9\tex\latex\beamer\beamerbaselocalstructure.sty"
("C:\Program Files\MiKTeX 2.9\tex\latex\tools\enumerate.sty"
Package: enumerate 2015/07/23 v3.00 enumerate extensions (DPC)
\@enLab=\toks31
)
\c@figure=\count139
\c@table=\count140
\abovecaptionskip=\skip49
\belowcaptionskip=\skip50
)
("C:\Program Files\MiKTeX 2.9\tex\latex\beamer\beamerbasenavigation.sty"
\beamer@section@min@dim=\dimen175
)
("C:\Program Files\MiKTeX 2.9\tex\latex\beamer\beamerbasetheorems.sty"
("C:\Program Files\MiKTeX 2.9\tex\latex\amsmath\amsmath.sty"
Package: amsmath 2017/09/02 v2.17a AMS math features
\@mathmargin=\skip51
For additional information on amsmath, use the `?' option.
("C:\Program Files\MiKTeX 2.9\tex\latex\amsmath\amstext.sty"
Package: amstext 2000/06/29 v2.01 AMS text
("C:\Program Files\MiKTeX 2.9\tex\latex\amsmath\amsgen.sty"
File: amsgen.sty 1999/11/30 v2.0 generic functions
\@emptytoks=\toks32
\ex@=\dimen176
))
("C:\Program Files\MiKTeX 2.9\tex\latex\amsmath\amsbsy.sty"
Package: amsbsy 1999/11/29 v1.2d Bold Symbols
\pmbraise@=\dimen177
)
("C:\Program Files\MiKTeX 2.9\tex\latex\amsmath\amsopn.sty"
Package: amsopn 2016/03/08 v2.02 operator names
)
\inf@bad=\count141
LaTeX Info: Redefining \frac on input line 213.
\uproot@=\count142
\leftroot@=\count143
LaTeX Info: Redefining \overline on input line 375.
\classnum@=\count144
\DOTSCASE@=\count145
LaTeX Info: Redefining \ldots on input line 472.
LaTeX Info: Redefining \dots on input line 475.
LaTeX Info: Redefining \cdots on input line 596.
\Mathstrutbox@=\box51
\strutbox@=\box52
\big@size=\dimen178
LaTeX Font Info: Redeclaring font encoding OML on input line 712.
LaTeX Font Info: Redeclaring font encoding OMS on input line 713.
\macc@depth=\count146
\c@MaxMatrixCols=\count147
\dotsspace@=\muskip11
\c@parentequation=\count148
\dspbrk@lvl=\count149
\tag@help=\toks33
\row@=\count150
\column@=\count151
\maxfields@=\count152
\andhelp@=\toks34
\eqnshift@=\dimen179
\alignsep@=\dimen180
\tagshift@=\dimen181
\tagwidth@=\dimen182
\totwidth@=\dimen183
\lineht@=\dimen184
\@envbody=\toks35
\multlinegap=\skip52
\multlinetaggap=\skip53
\mathdisplay@stack=\toks36
LaTeX Info: Redefining \[ on input line 2817.
LaTeX Info: Redefining \] on input line 2818.
)
("C:\Program Files\MiKTeX 2.9\tex\latex\amscls\amsthm.sty"
Package: amsthm 2017/10/31 v2.20.4
\thm@style=\toks37
\thm@bodyfont=\toks38
\thm@headfont=\toks39
\thm@notefont=\toks40
\thm@headpunct=\toks41
\thm@preskip=\skip54
\thm@postskip=\skip55
\thm@headsep=\skip56
\dth@everypar=\toks42
)
\c@theorem=\count153
)
("C:\Program Files\MiKTeX 2.9\tex\latex\beamer\beamerbasethemes.sty"))
("C:\Program Files\MiKTeX 2.9\tex\latex\beamer\beamerthemedefault.sty"
("C:\Program Files\MiKTeX 2.9\tex\latex\beamer\beamerfontthemedefault.sty")
("C:\Program Files\MiKTeX 2.9\tex\latex\beamer\beamercolorthemedefault.sty")
("C:\Program Files\MiKTeX 2.9\tex\latex\beamer\beamerinnerthemedefault.sty"
\beamer@dima=\dimen185
\beamer@dimb=\dimen186
)
("C:\Program Files\MiKTeX 2.9\tex\latex\beamer\beamerouterthemedefault.sty")))
("C:\Program Files\MiKTeX 2.9\tex\latex\beamer\beamercolorthemeseahorse.sty")
("C:\Program Files\MiKTeX 2.9\tex\latex\adjustbox\adjustbox.sty"
Package: adjustbox 2018/04/08 v1.1 Adjusting TeX boxes (trim, clip, ...)
("C:\Program Files\MiKTeX 2.9\tex\latex\xkeyval\xkeyval.sty"
Package: xkeyval 2014/12/03 v2.7a package option processing (HA)
("C:\Program Files\MiKTeX 2.9\tex\generic\xkeyval\xkeyval.tex"
("C:\Program Files\MiKTeX 2.9\tex\generic\xkeyval\xkvutils.tex"
\XKV@toks=\toks43
\XKV@tempa@toks=\toks44
)
\XKV@depth=\count154
File: xkeyval.tex 2014/12/03 v2.7a key=value parser (HA)
))
("C:\Program Files\MiKTeX 2.9\tex\latex\adjustbox\adjcalc.sty"
Package: adjcalc 2012/05/16 v1.1 Provides advanced setlength with multiple back
-ends (calc, etex, pgfmath)
)
("C:\Program Files\MiKTeX 2.9\tex\latex\adjustbox\trimclip.sty"
Package: trimclip 2018/04/08 v1.1 Trim and clip general TeX material
("C:\Program Files\MiKTeX 2.9\tex\latex\collectbox\collectbox.sty"
Package: collectbox 2012/05/17 v0.4b Collect macro arguments as boxes
\collectedbox=\box53
)
\tc@llx=\dimen187
\tc@lly=\dimen188
\tc@urx=\dimen189
\tc@ury=\dimen190
Package trimclip Info: Using driver 'tc-pdftex.def'.
("C:\Program Files\MiKTeX 2.9\tex\latex\adjustbox\tc-pdftex.def"
File: tc-pdftex.def 2018/04/08 v2.1 Clipping driver for pdftex
))
\adjbox@Width=\dimen191
\adjbox@Height=\dimen192
\adjbox@Depth=\dimen193
\adjbox@Totalheight=\dimen194
\adjbox@pwidth=\dimen195
\adjbox@pheight=\dimen196
\adjbox@pdepth=\dimen197
\adjbox@ptotalheight=\dimen198
("C:\Program Files\MiKTeX 2.9\tex\latex\ifoddpage\ifoddpage.sty"
Package: ifoddpage 2016/04/23 v1.1 Conditionals for odd/even page detection
\c@checkoddpage=\count155
)
("C:\Program Files\MiKTeX 2.9\tex\latex\ltxmisc\varwidth.sty"
Package: varwidth 2009/03/30 ver 0.92; Variable-width minipages
\@vwid@box=\box54
\sift@deathcycles=\count156
\@vwid@loff=\dimen199
\@vwid@roff=\dimen256
))
("C:\Program Files\MiKTeX 2.9\tex\latex\wrapfig\wrapfig.sty"
\wrapoverhang=\dimen257
\WF@size=\dimen258
\c@WF@wrappedlines=\count157
\WF@box=\box55
\WF@everypar=\toks45
Package: wrapfig 2003/01/31 v 3.6
)
("C:\Program Files\MiKTeX 2.9\tex\latex\lipsum\lipsum.sty"
Package: lipsum 2014/07/27 v1.3 150 paragraphs of Lorem Ipsum dummy text
\c@lips@count=\count158
)
("C:\Program Files\MiKTeX 2.9\tex\latex\booktabs\booktabs.sty"
Package: booktabs 2005/04/14 v1.61803 publication quality tables
\heavyrulewidth=\dimen259
\lightrulewidth=\dimen260
\cmidrulewidth=\dimen261
\belowrulesep=\dimen262
\belowbottomsep=\dimen263
\aboverulesep=\dimen264
\abovetopsep=\dimen265
\cmidrulesep=\dimen266
\cmidrulekern=\dimen267
\defaultaddspace=\dimen268
\@cmidla=\count159
\@cmidlb=\count160
\@aboverulesep=\dimen269
\@belowrulesep=\dimen270
\@thisruleclass=\count161
\@lastruleclass=\count162
\@thisrulewidth=\dimen271
)
(Pre_Submission_home1.aux)
\openout1 = `Pre_Submission_home1.aux'.
LaTeX Font Info: Checking defaults for OML/cmm/m/it on input line 8.
LaTeX Font Info: ... okay on input line 8.
LaTeX Font Info: Checking defaults for T1/cmr/m/n on input line 8.
LaTeX Font Info: ... okay on input line 8.
LaTeX Font Info: Checking defaults for OT1/cmr/m/n on input line 8.
LaTeX Font Info: ... okay on input line 8.
LaTeX Font Info: Checking defaults for OMS/cmsy/m/n on input line 8.
LaTeX Font Info: ... okay on input line 8.
LaTeX Font Info: Checking defaults for OMX/cmex/m/n on input line 8.
LaTeX Font Info: ... okay on input line 8.
LaTeX Font Info: Checking defaults for U/cmr/m/n on input line 8.
LaTeX Font Info: ... okay on input line 8.
LaTeX Font Info: Checking defaults for PD1/pdf/m/n on input line 8.
LaTeX Font Info: ... okay on input line 8.
*geometry* driver: auto-detecting
*geometry* detected driver: pdftex
*geometry* verbose mode - [ preamble ] result:
* driver: pdftex
* paper: custom
* layout: <same size as paper>
* layoutoffset:(h,v)=(0.0pt,0.0pt)
* modes: includehead includefoot
* h-part:(L,W,R)=(28.45274pt, 307.28987pt, 28.45274pt)
* v-part:(T,H,B)=(0.0pt, 273.14662pt, 0.0pt)
* \paperwidth=364.19536pt
* \paperheight=273.14662pt
* \textwidth=307.28987pt
* \textheight=244.6939pt
* \oddsidemargin=-43.81725pt
* \evensidemargin=-43.81725pt
* \topmargin=-72.26999pt
* \headheight=14.22636pt
* \headsep=0.0pt
* \topskip=11.0pt
* \footskip=14.22636pt
* \marginparwidth=4.0pt
* \marginparsep=10.0pt
* \columnsep=10.0pt
* \skip\footins=10.0pt plus 4.0pt minus 2.0pt
* \hoffset=0.0pt
* \voffset=0.0pt
* \mag=1000
* \@twocolumnfalse
* \@twosidefalse
* \@mparswitchfalse
* \@reversemarginfalse
* (1in=72.27pt=25.4mm, 1cm=28.453pt)
("C:\Program Files\MiKTeX 2.9\tex\context\base\supp-pdf.mkii"
[Loading MPS to PDF converter (version 2006.09.02).]
\scratchcounter=\count163
\scratchdimen=\dimen272
\scratchbox=\box56
\nofMPsegments=\count164
\nofMParguments=\count165
\everyMPshowfont=\toks46
\MPscratchCnt=\count166
\MPscratchDim=\dimen273
\MPnumerator=\count167
\makeMPintoPDFobject=\count168
\everyMPtoPDFconversion=\toks47
) ("C:\Program Files\MiKTeX 2.9\tex\latex\oberdiek\epstopdf-base.sty"
Package: epstopdf-base 2016/05/15 v2.6 Base part for package epstopdf
("C:\Program Files\MiKTeX 2.9\tex\latex\oberdiek\grfext.sty"
Package: grfext 2016/05/16 v1.2 Manage graphics extensions (HO)
)
Package epstopdf-base Info: Redefining graphics rule for `.eps' on input line 4
38.
Package grfext Info: Graphics extension search list:
(grfext) [.pdf,.png,.jpg,.mps,.jpeg,.jbig2,.jb2,.PDF,.PNG,.JPG,.JPE
G,.JBIG2,.JB2,.eps]
(grfext) \AppendGraphicsExtensions on input line 456.
)
ABD: EveryShipout initializing macros
\AtBeginShipoutBox=\box57
Package hyperref Info: Link coloring OFF on input line 8.
("C:\Program Files\MiKTeX 2.9\tex\latex\hyperref\nameref.sty"
Package: nameref 2016/05/21 v2.44 Cross-referencing by name of section
("C:\Program Files\MiKTeX 2.9\tex\generic\oberdiek\gettitlestring.sty"
Package: gettitlestring 2016/05/16 v1.5 Cleanup title references (HO)
)
\c@section@level=\count169
)
LaTeX Info: Redefining \ref on input line 8.
LaTeX Info: Redefining \pageref on input line 8.
LaTeX Info: Redefining \nameref on input line 8.
(Pre_Submission_home1.out) (Pre_Submission_home1.out)
\@outlinefile=\write5
\openout5 = `Pre_Submission_home1.out'.
LaTeX Font Info: Overwriting symbol font `operators' in version `normal'
(Font) OT1/cmr/m/n --> OT1/cmss/m/n on input line 8.
LaTeX Font Info: Overwriting symbol font `operators' in version `bold'
(Font) OT1/cmr/bx/n --> OT1/cmss/bx/n on input line 8.
\symnumbers=\mathgroup6
\sympureletters=\mathgroup7
LaTeX Font Info: Overwriting math alphabet `\mathrm' in version `normal'
(Font) OT1/cmss/m/n --> OT1/cmr/m/n on input line 8.
[...]
("C:\Program Files\MiKTeX 2.9\tex\latex\translator\translator-basic-dictionary-
English.dict"
Dictionary: translator-basic-dictionary, Language: English
)
("C:\Program Files\MiKTeX 2.9\tex\latex\translator\translator-bibliography-dict
ionary-English.dict"
Dictionary: translator-bibliography-dictionary, Language: English
)
("C:\Program Files\MiKTeX 2.9\tex\latex\translator\translator-environment-dicti
onary-English.dict"
Dictionary: translator-environment-dictionary, Language: English
)
("C:\Program Files\MiKTeX 2.9\tex\latex\translator\translator-months-dictionary
-English.dict"
Dictionary: translator-months-dictionary, Language: English
)
("C:\Program Files\MiKTeX 2.9\tex\latex\translator\translator-numbers-dictionar
y-English.dict"
Dictionary: translator-numbers-dictionary, Language: English
)
("C:\Program Files\MiKTeX 2.9\tex\latex\translator\translator-theorem-dictionar
y-English.dict"
Dictionary: translator-theorem-dictionary, Language: English
) (Pre_Submission_home1.nav)
LaTeX Font Info: Try loading font information for U+msa on input line 15.
("C:\Program Files\MiKTeX 2.9\tex\latex\amsfonts\umsa.fd"
File: umsa.fd 2013/01/14 v3.01 AMS symbols A
)
LaTeX Font Info: Try loading font information for U+msb on input line 15.
("C:\Program Files\MiKTeX 2.9\tex\latex\amsfonts\umsb.fd"
File: umsb.fd 2013/01/14 v3.01 AMS symbols B
)
LaTeX Font Info: Try loading font information for OT1+mathkerncmss on input
line 15.
("C:\Program Files\MiKTeX 2.9\tex\latex\sansmathaccent\ot1mathkerncmss.fd"
File: ot1mathkerncmss.fd 2013/03/27 Fontinst v1.933 font definitions for OT1/ma
thkerncmss.
)
[1
{C:/Users/Rahul/AppData/Local/MiKTeX/2.9/pdftex/config/pdftex.map}]
\tf@nav=\write6
\openout6 = `Pre_Submission_home1.nav'.
\tf@toc=\write7
\openout7 = `Pre_Submission_home1.toc'.
\tf@snm=\write8
\openout8 = `Pre_Submission_home1.snm'.
Package atveryend Info: Empty hook `BeforeClearDocument' on input line 16.
Package atveryend Info: Empty hook `AfterLastShipout' on input line 16.
(Pre_Submission_home1.aux)
Package atveryend Info: Executing hook `AtVeryEndDocument' on input line 16.
Package atveryend Info: Executing hook `AtEndAfterFileList' on input line 16.
Package rerunfilecheck Info: File `Pre_Submission_home1.out' has not changed.
(rerunfilecheck) Checksum: D41D8CD98F00B204E9800998ECF8427E;0.
)
Here is how much of TeX's memory you used:
17977 strings out of 493305
336317 string characters out of 3138874
508118 words of memory out of 3000000
21107 multiletter control sequences out of 15000+200000
10083 words of font info for 37 fonts, out of 3000000 for 9000
1141 hyphenation exceptions out of 8191
56i,14n,55p,810b,557s stack positions out of 5000i,500n,10000p,200000b,50000s
!pdfTeX error: pdflatex (file mathkerncmssi8): Font mathkerncmssi8 at 600 not f
ound
==> Fatal error occurred, no output PDF file produced
```

Comment: We need more info, maybe log messages. If you don't show us the error, how to help you? Please, edit your post and show us.

Comment: Can you show us your .log file?

Comment: I have deleted some lines in starting of the Log file because that exceeded the limit of 30000.

Comment: @Rahul Can you post the start of the log file? If there is not enough space in your question, try https://pastebin.com/

Comment: I have pasted full Log File on this url https://pastebin.com/UnKus8hv

Comment: https://pastebin.com/UnKus8hv

Comment: OK, the problem is that a font is not found `!pdfTeX error: pdflatex (file mathkerncmssi8): Font mathkerncmssi8 at 600 not f
ound
`

Comment: Try this answer: https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/64790/36296

Comment: or this one: https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/115765/problem-with-font-map/115873#115873

Comment: Thanks a lot, adding \pdfmapfile{+sansmathaccent.map} in my document does the trick. However I am not able to find its permanent solution on both the links. How can I open the UPDMP file ?? and how can i add line Map sansmathaccent.map. But for now I can make PPT for my PhD Pre Submission. Thanks

Comment: Run in the miktex console (user mode) the task "refresh font map files".

Comment: Thank you dear Fischer, Now my file is running automatically thanks once again.

Comment: hey one last problem, which I did not notice earlier the output shrink to right side. What cause this problem ?

Comment: @Rahul What exactly do you mean with "the output shrink to right side"? (if you reply to someone, please start the comment with @<username> to notify them about your reply)